# run Java class Main in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I has problem with android studio run java with sample main. Now, it run main with gradle Executing task, how run default java main default. This is image gradle executing task not java run. With java run, it is not show gradle run below:
[image]

I want run java sample below:
[image]

Can you help run default java in android studio not gradle executing? Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

You can run java programs from the terminal without gradle like this :

First compile your java code to class:

```
javac Foo.java
```

Then run it using this command :

```
java -classpath <Package location> <main class name>
```

For example :

```
java -classpath C:\AndroidStudioProjects\app\src\main\java\ com.example.Foo
```

Comment: I run with lib import and class java main.:((

Comment: Before i run with java run, but after i run gradle excuting. i don't know why i switch run gradle excuting.

Comment: @QuestionAndroid if u are using external libraries , you can put their paths in the classpath also.

Comment: Current, i run coverage, same java run. thank you